# Duplicate files copied in Android

Tags: java, android

I added two libraries into my android project they are called:

```
commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

And i defined them in `build.gradle` as :

1. `compile files ('libs/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar')`
2. `compile files ('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')`

When i run my program i get this error, although i deleted LICENSE.txt File. Maybe someone else had this problem before or any suggestions how to solve this?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>       File 1: C:\Users\Girts\AndroidStudioProjects\App\app\libs\commons-logging-1.2.jar
>       File 2: C:\Users\Girts\AndroidStudioProjects\App\app\libs\commons-logging-1.2.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution just had to add this code in build.gradle and it will ignore it

```
android {
     packagingOptions { 
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' 
     }
 }
```